# Direction property makes hiding the horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, direction

I have a weird conflict in my web page.

When I'm resizing my web page window to small, there is no horizontal scrollbar.

I checked my body css, but there is no `overflow-x` property. and when I'm using `overflow-x: scroll;` the scrollbar is visible, but cannot detect overflow (grey scrollbar).

But I found the problem. the problem is coming from `direction:rtl;` property.
this is my body css code:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
background-image: url("../images/bg_body.jpg");
background-position: 50% 0;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #000;
direction: rtl;
font: 11px/150% Tahoma;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
text-align: justify;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 980px;
```

after I removed `direction: rtl;` scrollbar appeared.
also when I added `dir="rtl"` to body tag in HTML file, issue still persist.
`dir="ltr"`made this problem too.

Any idea why this conflict happened?

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle.

Comment: @logan I tried it. The scrollbar works in fiddle correctly.

Comment: have you tried overflow:auto, so the scroll bar occurs in both ways